# Security test cases for Payment module in eCommerce sites?

Tags: manual-testing, functional

I'm writing test cases for eCommerce site checkout flow. So as part of that, I'm looking for negative cases where checkout can go wrong around the payment area as the main scope lies in it.

Comment: What are the risks you are trying to investigate? Which weakness have you perceived in your exploration?

Comment: Able to complete an order with no products in cart

Answer (score 2):

Below are the few test cases that used by QA in software testing company to test the Payment systems:

- Check what happens if payment gateway stops responding during payment
- Check what happens if payment process fails
- Check what happens if internet stop during payment process
- Check what happens if user close the application portal during
  payment process
- During the payment process check what happens if the session ends
- After successful transaction check if the payment gateway returns to
  your application
- Check if each listed payment option opens the respective  payment
  option according to specification
- Check if each of the payment options are selectable
- Check if the number being added into the credit card number field
  detects the type of card